# Most efficient way to fill this specific 9x9 grid

Tags: combinations, puzzle, discrete-optimization

I've been thinking about this question for a while.

Say, you have a 9x9 grid. Each of these grids can have a state - nothing, supplier, and a generator. A supplier can supply 1 unit to each generator nearby it, including diagonals, to a maximum of 8 generators. A generator cannot work unless it is powered by a supplier.

What's the most efficient way to place these to get the greatest number of generators?

Comment: Can a supplier provide power to multiple generators nearby? If so, place a supplier in the middle of the grid, with 8 generators around it.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... Since you have been thinking about this problem for a while, please include your thoughts with the problem. This will help answerers avoid wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining strategies you've already considered. (Also, isolated problem statements are discouraged here, as they come across as do-my-work-for-me requests.) ... BTW: If you want "the greatest number of generators", then just put one in each square, for a maximum of $81$. If you want "the greatest number of **working** generators", then that's different. ;)

Comment: Why don't you interact with the comments by Stefan Lafon and Blue ? Does it mean that you are waiting for a "ready made" solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g \ge 0$ be the number of generators and $s \ge 0$ the number of suppliers.  You want to maximize $g$ subject to
\begin{align}
g+s &\le 81 \tag1\label1\\
g -8s &\le 0 \tag2\label2
\end{align}
Now multiplying constraint \eqref{1} by $8/9$ and constraint \eqref{2} by $1/9$ and adding them up yields $g \le 72$, which is attainable by placing a supplier in the middle of each $3 \times 3$ "Sudoku" subgrid:
[image]

For a $10 \times 10$ grid, the same approach yields an upper bound of $\lfloor(8/9)10^2\rfloor = 88$, which is not attainable.  Via integer linear programming, with two binary decision variables per cell, the maximum turns out to be $84$:
[image]

Comment: One more question: how would this work in the case of an even width+height? Like a 10x10 grid?

Comment: @hamza I updated my answer to include $10 \times 10$.